# Cursor from EditText gone over after override getText()

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor, gettext

I need to getText() returns the text with a single space between words and removes all spaces at the beginning and end of the line. To implement these requirements, I overrided this method in edittext:

```
@Override
public Editable getText() {
    String text = super.getText().toString();
    text = text.trim();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if ((i + 1) >= text.length() || text.charAt(i) != ' ' || text.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {
            builder.append(text.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    Editable e = new SpannableStringBuilder(builder);
    return e;
}
```

But then no longer displayed the cursor when entering text. I have tried several ways to display it in the code and XML, but nothing helped. **Is it possible to somehow fix this bug?**

 My `CutomEditText` class extends `AppCompatEditText`

Comment: can't you get the text the from getText() method and then can do the space removal thing rather than overriding the method.

Answer (score 2):

why are you doing such complication when you can do it easily

```
String data = "Where are you going"; // you can also use String data = edittext.getText()
String str[] = data.split(" ");
String filtered = "";
for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    if(i=0)
       filtered=trim(str[i]);
    else{
       filtered = " "+trim(str[i]); 
    }
}
```